# AWS CodeDeploy is impossible to deploy across multiple Availability Zones at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Below the screenshot, it seems to be successful only in one Availability Zone.
[image]

I checked the codedeploy logs for a failed instance, and I found that there was an error, I think it is recognized as an on-premise instance.

> 2018-01-10 04:40:22 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2696)]: **On Premises config file does not exist** or not readable
>
> 2018-01-10 04:40:43 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2696)]: CodeDeploy Instance Agent Service: CodeDeploy Instance Agent Service: error during start or run: InstanceMetadata::InstanceMetadataError - Not an EC2 instance and region not provided in the environment variable AWS_REGION. Please specify your region using environment variable AWS_REGION.......

I've searched for about three days for this issue, but there was no mention in the AWS documentation. In the production env, I plan to use two Availability Zones attached to the auto scaling group. I wonder if I'm overlooking the other thing except CodeDeploy... What should I check? Thank you in advance.

[Updated]
I update with ASG and ASG Config screent shot. There's no special, it's vanila and default process. I waiting 5 days from AWS support center but still pending response.

Auto Scaling Group -----
[image: Auto Scaling Group]

Auto Scaling Group Launch Config -----
[image: Auto Scaling Group Launch Config]

Comment: why don't you attach the ELB to codedeploy config instance of adding instances in two different instances ?

Comment: @KushVyas I have already tested with the ELB + ASG combination, but it still fails to deploy if the availability zone is different. To simplify the question, I have configured the situation.

Comment: Can you try login to that ec2 and post the output of  command `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data`

Comment: @Ravi There seems to be a problem with that instance. When I enter 169.254.169.254, I can not connect. On the other hand, the meta-data was correctly seen on the instances that was successfully deployed. This seems to be the problem. Is the AMI of my ASG Launch Config a problem? My AMI is in ap-southeast-1a, so the instances in ap-southeast-1b seems to fail to deploy.

Comment: @hyunsu AMIs are different by region, not by AZ, so as long as you're using the same AMI, it should work.

Comment: @hyunsu Is your launch config the same in both AZs? Can you post your launch config, at least that which relates to the agent, in your question?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal What's the meaning of "..launch config the samie in both AZs.."? I choose 2 AZs when "Create AutoScalingGroup" not "Create ASG Launch Config". Is there something I do not know? I'll update question to post launch config. Thank you.

Comment: @hyunsu You're right. What I really meant: Do both your successful hosts and unsuccessful hosts use the same launch config?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal Definetly yes.I use only 1 launch configuration at that time. And they are(successful hosts and failed hosts) launched from same launch configuration.

Comment: While you may only use one launch config at a time, depending on your ASG update policy, it may not actually replace instances when you update the launch config, meaning that instances were set up with different launch and may differ. However, I see that you don't use `userData` to install the agent, so you must do so manually? Did you potentially call `aws deploy register` on the faulty instance? If you can afford to replace the host, it might be easiest to just recycle the host and spin up a new one. Perhaps a fresh start will do the job.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal "...it may not actually...... instances were set up with different launch and may differ..." But... how do that? The ASG do alomost instead of me, I just click "OK" and wait running instances. I'm very frustrated... I've installed codedeploy agent on AMI as service(Window) and I double checked running on instances. So I don't provide userData on launch config. May be is this problem...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found out why codedeploy failed across multiple availability zones on Windows 2016. Also, this problem seems to be an issue with Windows 2016 EC2 itself rather than ASG or codedeploy(I have not tested it on linux). There are 2 solutions I found,

1. Shut down the server safely by clicking the button "Shutdown with Syspre" in Ec2LaunchSettings. And then you can create AMI as usal.

[image: Ec2LaunchSetting GUI]

2. Run the C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule script manually. The argument "-Schedule" is required. And then you can create AMI as usal.

[image: InitializeInstance.ps1]

The first method is an intuitive and convenient way(GUI), and the second method is  appropriate for automate a powershell script. I have confirmed that both methods succeed in deploying to multiple AZs. There were no errors in the logs recorded by codedeployagent.

To be more specific, codedeployagent leaves various logs at the time of deployment, and I found that the agent seems to use meta-info from 169.254.169.254. When I failed, the log say "You are On-Premise Instance.". Probably the deployment fails because the instance can not get meta-info. In the following document, I have received a lot of help and all of my solutions are listed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html

Especially, in the document

> .....In Windows PowerShell, run the following command so that the system schedules the script to run as a Windows Scheduled Task. The script runs one time during the next boot and then disables these tasks from running again....

```
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule
```

Comment: Thank you all of your comments.